# Unilateral closing transaction for channel stuck in mempool

Tags: mempool, core-lightning, child-pays-for-parent

I've now had an unilateral closing of a channel stuck in the mempool for over two months. I want to transfer the unconfirmed sum to another wallet, so I want to create a new transaction which also is a CPFP transaction to the first transaction thus making it confirm faster. But I haven't been able to find a way to do it and would appreciate any guidance in how to do it, if it's even possible.

My lightning node is running Core Lightning v23.08.

And I don't see anything in `"outputs":[]` when running `lightning-cli listfunds`

Comment: Not an issue anymore for me transaction now confirmed after been 2 months in the mempool. It's the longest time I've had a transaction there. To me it shows the robustness of Bitcoin! This is still a problem tough if you want to escalate the transaction or just send the funds. But maybe there is an explanation I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed on the Core Lightning [community chat](https://community.corelightning.org/c/node-operators/is-it-possible-to-cpfp-closing-tx-that-uses-wrong-fee-too-low) in August 2023. grubles stated:

> You can do it manually if you use hsmtool to dump your CLN onchain descriptor, import that into bitcoind, create a PSBT with a higher fee, and sign it with CLN. Let me know if you want to give that a try.

At the time of writing (September 2023) there doesn't seem to be an easier way to do this.